# Confidence interval before or after target variable transformation?

Tags: data-transformation, standard-deviation

I created a machine learning model where I normalized the target variable in the training set before fitting the model. I then used a package which produced a standard deviation of eqch prediction. If I calculate the bound for a confidence interval of a prediction then transform the result I get a different value than if I transform the sd and the point estimator then calculate the bound.

Why does it matter when I perform the inverse transformation or am I totally incorrect and they should be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a logarithmic transformation:

$x'=\log(x)$.

If you estimate a normal based 95% confidence interval for the mean $\bar{x}'$, then:

$\exp(\bar{x}'\pm 1.96\cdot\text{SE}) \neq \exp(\bar{x}') \pm \exp(1.96\cdot\text{SE}) \neq \exp(\bar{x}') \pm 1.96\cdot\exp(\text{SE})$,
etc.

So if you obtain standard errors for a statistic estimated from your transformed variable, you should *first* use those to construct a confidence interval, and *then* use an inverse transformation on your lower and upper bound.

(In the example I gave, $\exp(\bar{x}'\pm 1.96\cdot\text{SE})$ is the right way to do it.)